# How to convert a boolean variable to unsigned char in c++?

Tags: c++11, types, type-conversion

I want to convert a variable of type bool to an unsigned char variable, I tried the following code, but it doesn´t work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jw18.png)

Comment: Include codes in question. Avoid links or images for codes.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this?

```html
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main() {
   bool my_bool;
   my_bool = true;
   cout << "The int equivalent of my_bool is: " << (unsigned char)(my_bool) << endl;
   my_bool = false;
   cout << "The int equivalent of my_bool is: " << (unsigned char)(my_bool);
}
```

Comment: is more like assign to an unsigned char variable the conversion of a bool variable, like this:                                                                                                                                                                                                          bool a = true;                                                                                                                           unsigned char B = static_cast<unsigned char>(a);

Comment: With this I what that the value of B be now  '1',  and case the value of a be false, i wan that the value of B be '0', the equivalent in unsigned char of a bool type

Comment: so you dont care if it is signed or unsigned. You want char "0" and char "1" so just erase "unsigned" form my code and it will work.